# Expand Databound Treeview Item WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

how can I expand my bound item in treeview?

My item's class:

```
public class TreeViewItemBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return this.isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.isSelected)
            {
                this.isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return this.isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.isExpanded)
            {
                this.isExpanded = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
public class FileModelViewTreeView : TreeViewItemBase
{
    public int Level
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public List<FileModelViewTreeView> SubItems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't works by me:

```
((FileModelViewTreeView)toSelectIndex).IsExpanded = true;
((FileModelViewTreeView)toSelectIndex).IsSelected = true;
```

My treeview xaml code:

```
<TreeView SelectedItemChanged="FilesTreeView_SelectedItemChanged" x:Name="FilesTreeView" Margin="0,68,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#4c607a" BorderThickness="2">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileModelViewTreeView}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/UI/Images/dir.png"
                       Width="21"
                       Height="21"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                        <TextBlock Padding="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

All solutions which I found on other forums didn't worked for me :(
There are no exception at runtime and compiling, it just doesn't works. Maybe anyone already had that problem, please help me.

Comment: You aren't using the TreeViewItemBase properties anywhere, so what exactly is your expectation? You might have a TreeViewItem Style as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21123719/1136211

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74560208/set-isselected-properties-of-treeviewitem-in-treeview-wpf-mvvm/74585274#74585274

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is using a style.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTreeViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ...
</style>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemContainerStyle}" />
</Style>
```

Check out my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/) for my take on how to handle WPF TreeViews in a MVVM context.

Comment: Hey Peregrine,
I got another error using this code "Property IsExpanded not found."
Do you have any ideas?