# Set isselected properties of TreeViewItem in TreeView WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

i am a newbie to WPF mvvm, i created a treeview and i want to set isSelected value of a specific treeviewitem in this tree (for example, item with "19-ASDFDSSD") but i dont know how to do it. Can you help me? Any help will be appreciated.

[treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le5xo.png)
[wpf code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaAQy.png)

[JobsDTOClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXTBe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TreeView.SelectedItem` is read only, so a value can't be pushed from the ViewModel.

The way I've handled this is via the use of a `Behavior` class.

1 - Create a base class for TreeView item data, that includes IsSelected and IsExpanded properties.

```
public class perTreeViewItemViewModelBase : perViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set => Set(nameof(IsSelected), ref _isSelected, value);
    }

    private bool _isExpanded;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set => Set(nameof(IsExpanded), ref _isExpanded, value);
    }


    ...
}
```

2 - Create a helper class for TreeView controls to implement the behavior, with a `BoundSelectedItem` attached property.

```
public class perTreeViewHelper : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public object BoundSelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedItem",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(perTreeViewHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnBoundSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnBoundSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue is perTreeViewItemViewModelBase item)
        {
            item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object obj, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        BoundSelectedItem = args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

3 - Create styles for TreeViewItem and TreeView to bind the IsSelected property of the perTreeViewItemViewModelBase instance to the corresponding TreeViewItem property

```
<Style x:Key="perTreeViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <!--  Link the properties of perTreeViewItemViewModelBase to the corresponding ones on the TreeViewItem  -->
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    ...

</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource perTreeViewItemContainerStyle}" />
</Style>
```

4 - In the View, use the behavior class to bind the BoundSelectedItem attached proprety to a corresponding property in the ViewModel

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <vhelp:perTreeViewHelper BoundSelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

For more details on my take on how to handle TreeView controls in a MVVM context (including check boxes for item selection and lazy loading of item data), check out my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhhhhhh, your solution is a little bit complicated for me, but i guest i know how it work. To simplify your solution, i added an bool "IsSelected" attribute to my JobsDTO class and add <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected> to my wpf. So if i want to set selected a job in my tree view, i will change it to true.